# converting Polygon to array of bounding box

Tags: java, polygon, bounding-box

I'm looking for an algorithm that converts polygon (i.e. array of points) into an array of bounding boxes (with given tolerance).

See the following (incomplete) example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After additional investigation, I figure that I can use [jillesvangurp](https://github.com/jillesvangurp/geogeometry) excellent library in order to get a Set of geo-hashes, and then decode them to list of bounding boxes.

sample code:

```
Set<String> geoHashesForPolygon = GeoHashUtils.geoHashesForPolygon(points);
List<BoundingBox> bboxes = new ArrayList<>(geoHashesForPolygon.size());
for (String geoHash : geoHashesForPolygon) {
    double[] bbox = GeoHashUtils.decode_bbox(geoHash);
    bboxes.add(new BoundingBox(bbox));
}
```

Comment: Perfect ans.. But will all those geohash created in the polygon be of same precision...?